# Cross-browser mask-image/-webkit-mask-image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

how can I mask some png files with textures, for example, gold silver or ...
for instance, I have an image like this:
[the original png image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWK09.png) 
is there any ways to use the texture below: 
[The sample texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9TJq.jpg) 
to make it like the following picture by using CSS, jquery and ...!
[example for image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY3E8.png)

I searched a lot but unfortunately didn't see any acceptable result
thanks

---

**Updated!**

I find out one way by myself! just using CSS and jquery
the HTML code just for showing textures and buttons is:

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-sm-11">
<img id="pic" src="img/goldtexture.jpg">
    </div>

   <div class="btn btn-group margin">
        <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default gold">gold</button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default silver">silver</button>
        </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default bronze">bronze</button>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
 #pic{
    width: 180px;
    height: 95px;
    background:yellow;
    mask-image:url(img/pic.png);
    -webkit-mask-image:url(img/pic.png);
    margin-left: 40%;
}
```

and my jquery code:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.gold').click(function(){
            $('#pic').attr('src','img/goldtexture.jpg');


        });
    $('.silver').click(function(){
        $('#pic').attr('src','img/silvertexture.jpg');

        });
        $('.bronze').click(function(){
            $('#pic').attr('src','img/bronzetexture.jpg');
        });
    });
```

In this way everything is ok and there is no problem with the result but unfortunately, just a few browsers support the mask-image CSS property ...
I'll so happy if there any better way to do this
wait for your answers

Comment: my question is pretty clear to understand! why told me I'm asking multiple distinct questions!?

Comment: Question seems fine to me.

Comment: @Brad thanks bro, it's because you're extremely intelligent!